# Computing Variance and Expected Value With Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation, chebyshev-polynomials

Consider tossing an unbiased coin until we see exactly *k* heads. Let Y be the
random variable corresponding to the total number of coin tosses required.

My instructor has given the following hint: Let $Y = X1+X2+. . .+Xk$ where $Xi$ is the number of extra coin tosses required after the (i − 1)th head is observed until the *ith* head is observed.

- Compute $E(Y)$

  > I'm thinking of using a summation of sorts to do here. Perhaps $\sum{Xi}\frac{1}{2}$? I'm trying to figure out how to imply the hint my professor gave into this. I also notice that each $Xi$ is the same type of random variable. I'm thinking to use something around the **Linearity of Expectation** to determine the answer.
- Compute var(Y)

  > If I can get E(Y), this is incredibly straight-forward.
- Define Z = Y /k: Compute E(Z) and var(Z)

  > I'm assuming that it would be the same process as E(Y), except I would replace a variable in the summation with Y/k.
- Use the Chebyshev bound to prove a bound on P(|Z − E(Z)| ≥ 2) in terms of k.

  > I currently have that $P(|Z-\mu|≥k\sigma) \,≤\,\frac {1}{k^2}$, however, I am stuck with obtaining the proper variance for this. This means that $\sigma = E(Z)$ but I cannot figure out the other variables.

Everything I've attempted so far is incorrect merely because I am incorrectly interpreting different statistical rules. Work would be highly appreciated in assistance to figuring these out.

Comment: The distribution of $Y$ is a *negative binomial*.

Comment: @mlc Aye, I also reached that conclusion. However, its the steps that lay ahead that still have me bogged down.

Comment: @mlc If you wouldn't mind, would you please expand a little bit on how to use the fact that Y is a negative binomial to start the problem? It would go a long way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some  pointers that may help the OP to  get started.  We have
from first principles that the probability of needing $T$ samples that
it is given by

$$P[T=m] = \frac{1}{2^m} {m-1\choose k-1}.$$

Let us verify that this is a probability distribution:

$$\sum_{m\ge k} P[T=m] = \sum_{m\ge k} \frac{1}{2^m} {m-1\choose k-1}
= \frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{2^m} {m+k-1\choose k-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{m\ge 0} 
\frac{1}{2^m} [z^m] \frac{1}{(1-z)^k}
= \frac{1}{2^k} \frac{1}{(1/2)^k} = 1$$

and the sanity check goes through. We get for the factorial moments

$$\mathrm{E}[T(T-1)\ldots (T-(\ell-1))] = 
\sum_{m\ge k} {m\choose \ell} \ell! P[T=m] 
\\ = \ell! \sum_{m\ge k} {m\choose \ell} \frac{1}{2^m} {m-1\choose k-1}
= \ell! \frac{1}{2^k} 
\sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{2^m} {m+k\choose \ell} {m+k-1\choose k-1}
\\ = \ell! \frac{1}{2^k} 
\sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{2^m} {m+k-1\choose k-1} 
[z^\ell] (1+z)^{m+k}
\\ = \ell! [z^\ell] \frac{(1+z)^k}{2^k} 
\sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{2^m} {m+k-1\choose k-1} (1+z)^{m}
\\ = \ell! [z^\ell] \frac{(1+z)^k}{2^k} \frac{1}{(1-(1+z)/2)^k}
= \ell! [z^\ell] \frac{(1+z)^k}{(1-z)^k}.$$

This is

$$\ell! \sum_{r=0}^\ell {k\choose r} {\ell-r+k-1\choose k-1}.$$

We thus obtain

$$\mathrm{E}[T] = 1\times {k\choose k-1}
+ k\times {k-1\choose k-1} = 2k$$

Furthermore

$$\mathrm{E}[T(T-1)] = 2\times 1\times {k+1\choose k-1}
+ 2\times k\times {k\choose k-1}
+ 2\times {k\choose 2}\times {k-1\choose k-1}
\\ = (k+1)k + 2k^2 + k(k-1)
= 4k^2.$$

This yields for the variance

$$\mathrm{Var}[T] = \mathrm{E}[T(T-1)] + \mathrm{E}[T]
- \mathrm{E}[T]^2 = 4 k^2 + 2k - (2k)^2 = 2k.$$

Observe that when we consult e.g.  [Wikipedia on the negative binomial
distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)
we find  that most  entries like  the German one  and the  English one
present two varieties of this distribution, one of them where only the
number of  successes is counted i.e.  the  non-constant statistic, and
another where  we count  the total number  of trials. It  appears this
question asks for the latter, which is what we computed above.

The following extremely  simple Perl script can be  used to verify the
factorial moments that were  obtained and documents the interpretation
of the question that was used.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

MAIN: {
    my $k = shift || 5;
    my $l = shift || 1;
    my $trials = shift || 1000;

    print "$k $l $trials\n";

    my $data = 0;

    for(my $tind = 0; $tind < $trials; $tind++){
        my $seen = 0; my $steps = 0;

        while($seen < $k){
            my $result = int(rand(2));
            $steps++;

            $seen++ if $result == 1;
        }

        my $moment = 1;
        for(my $r = 0; $r < $l; $r++){
            $moment *= ($steps - $r);
        }

        $data += $moment;
    }

    print $data/$trials;
    print "\n";

    1;
}
```